# Why isn't my sorting algorithm working?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I'm developing a system for a client that creates a csv of packing labels which is sent to a printer. The client has six different items. Customers order products in bulk from my client. Two items (product A and product B) share the same packing line. In order to make packing more efficient my client wants to alternate between packing product A and packing product B first.

For example, if John, Sally, and James all ordered both products, the system needs to write John's orders to the csv starting with product A, Sally's orders starting with product B, and James' orders starting with product A again.

I've pasted my non-working code below, but this is really screwing with my head and I'm having a really tough time with it.

```
foreach($orders as $order) {

    $name = null;
    $phone = null;

    $account = DAO_ContactPerson::get($order->account_id);
    $delivery = false;
    if($account->is_agency) {
        $name = $order->getAttribute('name');
        $phone = $order->getAttribute('phone');
    } else {
        $name = sprintf("%s %s",
            $account->getPrimaryAddress()->first_name,
            $account->getPrimaryAddress()->last_name
        );
        $phone = $account->phone;
    }

    $name = trim($name);
    $phone = trim($phone);
    $items = $order->getItems();

    if($order->getAttribute('delivery')) {
        $type = 'deliveries';
        $destination = 'Delivery';
        $address = sprintf("%s %s %s",
            $order->getAttribute('delivery_address.line1'),
            $order->getAttribute('delivery_address.line2'),
            $order->getAttribute('delivery_address.postal')
        );
    } else {
        $type = 'pickups';
        $agency = DAO_ContactPerson::getAgency($order->getAttribute('pickup'));
        $destination = $agency->name;

        // Override account id so orders are grouped by agency
        $order->account_id = $agency->id;
        $address = null;
    }
//          var_dump($order->id);
    // Init account array
    if(!isset($rows[$type][$order->account_id]))
        $rows[$type][$order->account_id] = array('combined' => array(), 'separate' => array());

    foreach($items as $item) {
        $packing = 'separated';
        if($item->product_id == 3 || $item->product_id == 4)
            $packing = 'combined';

        if(!isset($rows[$type][$order->account_id][$packing][$item->product_id]))
            $rows[$type][$order->account_id][$packing][$item->product_id] = array();
        $i = 0;
        while($i < $item->quantity) {
            $rows[$type][$order->account_id][$packing][$item->product_id][] = array(
                    'number' => $order->id,
                    'destination' => $destination,
                    'size' => $item->product_id,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'address' => $address,
                    'phone' => $phone
                );
            $i++;
        }

    }
//          if($order->id == 176) {
//              var_dump($rows[$type][$order->account_id][$packing]);
//          }
}

$this->weight = 1;

$pickups = count($rows['pickups']);
for($i = 0; $i < $pickups; $i++) {
    $account =& $rows['pickups'][$i];
    $account['output'] = array();
    if(isset($account['combined'])) {
        $combined_products =& $account['combined'];
        if(!empty($combined_products)) {
            foreach($combined_products as $prod_id => $combined) {
                usort($combined_products[$prod_id], array($this, "_compareBoxes"));
            }
            // Flip weights once we finish with this account
            $last_box = end($combined_products);
            $last_box = array_pop($last_box);
            reset($combined_products);
            if($this->weight == 1) {
                $this->weight = -1;
                if($last_box['size'] == 3) {
                    asort($combined_products);
                }
            } else {
                if($last_box['size'] == 4) {
                    arsort($combined_products);
                }
                $this->weight = 1;
            }
            foreach($combined_products as $combined) {
                $account['output'][] = $combined;
            }
            foreach($account['separated'] as $separate) {
                $account['output'][] = $separate;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(isset($account['separated']))
            $account['output'] = $account['separated'];
    }
}

$deliveries = count($rows['deliveries']);
for($i = 0; $i < $deliveries; $i++) {
    $account =& $rows['deliveries'][$i];
    $account['output'] = array();
    if(isset($account['combined'])) {
        $combined_products =& $account['combined'];
        if(!empty($combined_products)) {
            foreach($combined_products as $prod_id => $combined) {
                usort($combined_products[$prod_id], array($this, "_compareBoxes"));
            }
            // Flip weights once we finish with this account
            $last_box = end($combined_products);
            $last_box = array_pop($last_box);
            reset($combined_products);
            if($this->weight == 1) {
                $this->weight = -1;
                if($last_box['size'] == 3) {
                    asort($combined_products);
                }
            } else {
                if($last_box['size'] == 4) {
                    arsort($combined_products);
                }
                $this->weight = 1;
            }
            foreach($combined_products as $combined) {
                $account['output'][] = $combined;
            }
            foreach($account['separated'] as $separate) {
                $account['output'][] = $separate;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(isset($account['separated']))
            $account['output'] = $account['separated'];
    }
}

$rows['output'] = $rows['pickups'];
array_push($rows['output'], $rows['deliveries']);

$output = '';
foreach($rows['output'] as $account_id => $boxes) {
    if(!empty($boxes['output'])) {
        foreach($boxes['output'] as $labels) {
            if(!empty($labels)) {
                foreach($labels as $label) {
                    $output .= implode(',', $label) . "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The _compareBoxes method looks like this:

```
private function _compareBoxes($a, $b) {
    if($a['size'] == $b['size']) {
        return 0;
    }
    if($this->weight == 1) {
        // Medium first, then Large
        return ($a['size'] < $b['size']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if($this->weight == -1) {
        // Large first, then Medium
        return ($a['size'] > $b['size']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$account =& $rows['pickups'][$i];` Is this intended?

Comment: what is the problem? The array is not sorted accordingly? Error? Or?

Comment: These two statements in a row cause the first one to be ignored:  `$last_box = end($combined_products);` and `$last_box = array_pop($last_box);`.  That can't be good.

Comment: Could you give some input data for `$rows['pickups']`?

Comment: I've added more code for context.

The `$account =& $rows['pickups'][$i]` is intended. It assigns the variable by reference so when I change $accounts I'm really changing $rows['pickups'][$i].

The problem here is that it isn't sorted properly. It needs to flip between sorting from high to low then low to high once it is finished processing each account.

I've added some more code, though I'm really not sure it's going to help any. The ordered products are being read from the database then added to an array for pickups or deliveries.